# List View Column using Metadata Api

Tags: apex, list-view

I want to get List View Columns using Metadata available for ListViews. I have the Id and FullName of List Views but I want to get Column and Filter values using Id or Fullname. I am currently using SOAP Api but as it is not supported in lightning(Error 401), I want to use List View Id or FullName to get List View Columns and Filter criteria.. Thanks In advance!

Answer (score 1):

you can access Listview Columns,Filter Filte scope by Using `MetatadataAPI` [check out here](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi)  for how to use `MetatadataAPI` via Apex.

```
public class SFMetadataAPIService {
public static void readListViewMD() {
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = buildMDAPIService();
    MetadataService.ListView listView= (MetadataService.ListView) service.readMetadata(
        'ListView', new String[] { 'Account.businessAccounts' }
    ).getRecords()[0];

    if(listView.columns!=null)
        for(String column : listView.columns)
            System.Debug('Column ' + column)
    ;
    if(listView.filters!=null)
        for(MetadataService.ListViewFilter filter : listView.filters)
            System.Debug('Filter ' + filter.field + ' ' + filter.operation + ' ' + filter.value)
    ;
}
public static MetadataService.MetadataPort buildMDAPIService() {
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service= new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
        service.SessionHeader  = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
        service.SessionHeader.sessionId     = UserInfo.getSessionId();
      return service;
   }
}
```